# 16.04 Ubuntu server Screen flickers, unavailable to use the System

Tags: boot, server, graphics

I freshly installed Ubuntu server 16.04, and after trying to boot into it, the screen flickers in random colours(nothing else is shown). It won't boot far enough for SSH to be reachable. Does anyone know what I should do to fix this?

My hardware + settings are:

- GPU: Nvidia gtx 560 ti
- Processor: i7-2600k
- Bios mode for booting
- On-board video card for graphics(because I want to utilise the GPU for
  other things).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the old hardware needed a nomodeset.

To edit existing system to add nomodeset follow these steps

1. Press shift after Bios splash.
2. Select which kernel to boot and press e.
3. find the line which contains `linux /boot` etc
4. add nomodeset at the end
5. CTRL + X to reboot and the problem was solved

Somehow shift didn't do anything for me, but it made it possible to boot once with 'nomodeset' and then I set it myself in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: If it needed `nomodeset` you were using the Nvidia graphics, not Intel's.

Comment: Weird, my screen only works when plugged in to the motherboard, not the GPU.